# Label(s) may have changed warning in apager package

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

I'm trying do cite after the rules of "Deutsche Gesellschaft für Psychologie" which are similar to the ones of APA.

Therefore I downloaded a modification [here](http://www.openrepgrid.uni-bremen.de/data/apager_dgps.zip).

After deleting the line `\usepackage{Sweave}` (I have no idea, what this is for.) it produces two warnings:

1. `LaTeX Warning: You have requested package 'apager', but the package provides 'apacite'.`
2. `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`

I know how to fix the first:

Change line 40 in apager.sty from `\ProvidesPackage{apacite}[1994/11/30 APA citation]` to `\ProvidesPackage{apager}[1994/11/30 APA citation]`

But how to fix the second warning?

---

Additional question: What is the apager.bst file for?

Comment: Have you re-run LaTeX? I.E. have you run it at least twice? The warning says that basically in the normal procedure of running the anchors used to generate TOC and references in various places may have changed (new section, new float positioning, etc…). So, in order to have correct cross references, LaTeX tells you to re-run it.

Comment: I reran LaTeX several times.

Comment: @Ben Can you check if rerunning LaTeX causes any changes in the *content* of your .aux file?

Comment: The alteration date changes, but the two files are identical.

Comment: A bit sad to see that people take files and just change them to their gusto. Without doing the more important changes. *You* should not care about fixing the wrong package, you should rather make DGPS aware of the problem so they can fix it for *everybody* using their template.

Comment: This isn't an official solution. The DGPS doesn't provide a LaTeX solution. (Which are the really sad news.) Assuming by the URL, I guess it's a solution by the university Bremen.

Answer (score 1):

*Not a real answer to my question, but if someone else searches for a solution, here is mine.*

Just use [biblatex-apa](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa).

**Code:**

```
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
```

---

---

An alternative is to use [apalike-german](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apalike-german), but the author recommends to use BibLaTeX.